# Implementing lock based on status

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, thread-safety, locking

If I have a method like this:

```
public class Main()
{
  public void Start()
  {
     if(//Check if another thread already invoked this method and its in processing//)
       DoSomething();
  }

  void DoSomething()
  {
    //Some code in here
  }
}
```

How to use lock to Check if a thread is already executing DoSomething() then skip it ?

I know lock will make other calls wait, But I want to skip rather than wait and execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

tryLock

boolean tryLock()
Acquires the lock only if it is free at the time of invocation.
Acquires the lock if it is available and returns immediately with the value true. If the lock is not available then this method will return immediately with the value false.

A typical usage idiom for this method would be:

```
  Lock lock = ...;
  if (lock.tryLock()) {
      try {
          // manipulate protected state
      } finally {
          lock.unlock();
      }
  } else {
      // perform alternative actions
  }
```

This usage ensures that the lock is unlocked if it was acquired, and doesn't try to unlock if the lock was not acquired.
Returns:
true if the lock was acquired and false otherwise

Comment: What if the method will be called again right after the lock is freed?

Comment: the first  try call to acquire should get the lock